# Angular nested dynamic form

Tags: angular, angular-forms

How to make nested form in the way from angular.io documentation:

https://stackblitz.com/angular/pbdkbbnmrdg

Goal is to have two DropdownQuestion from question.service.ts in child formgroup named "details" and everything else like now in parent form...So at the end to look something like this:

```
{
    "firstName":"Bembasto",
    "email":"something@email.com",
    "details": {
      "dropdown1":{

      },
      "dropdown2":{

      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uros, you need undestand how the code create the FormGroup and how create the inputs.

We has a complex object that it's used to

1. Create the form
2. Show the inputs

First we are going to create a new type of control question-group

```
import { QuestionBase } from './question-base';

export class GroupQuestion extends QuestionBase<string> {
  controlType = 'group';
  type: string;

  constructor(options: {} = {}) {
    super(options);
  }
}
```

And add a new propertie to question-base

```
questions:any[];
//and change the constructor to allow give value
constructor(options: {
      value?: T,
      ...
      questions?:any[]
    } = {}) {
    this.value = options.value;
    ...
    this.questions = options.questions || [];
  }
```

Take a look how the code create the form. It's made in the question-control.service. Change the function toFormGroup to take account the typeControl "group"

```
toFormGroup(questions: QuestionBase<any>[] ) {
    let group: any = {};

    questions.forEach(question => {
      group[question.key] =  (question.controlType=='group')?
      this.toFormGroup(question.questions)
      :question.required ? new FormControl(question.value || '', Validators.required)
                                              : new FormControl(question.value || '');
    });
    return new FormGroup(group);
  }
```

Yes, we are using a recursive function. The idea we have is that we are going to have a question object like, e.g.

```
let questions: QuestionBase<any>[] = [
  new DropdownQuestion({
    ...
  }),
  new TextboxQuestion({
    ...
  })
  , new GroupQuestion(
    {
      key: 'details',
      label: 'Details',
      order: 2,
      questions: [
        new TextboxQuestion({
            ...
        }),
        new DropdownQuestion({
            ...
        })
      ]
    }
  )
];
```

Well, with this changes we have yet how create the formGroup but, how we show the inputs?
Before, we are going to change the dinamic-form-component to allow pass as argument the "form"

```
  @Input() form: FormGroup;
  subGroup:boolean=true;

  ngOnInit() {
    if (!this.form)
    {
      this.form = this.qcs.toFormGroup(this.questions);
      this.subGroup=false;
    }
  }
```

We add a new propertie "subGroup" to indicate if is a subgroup or not. So, we can hide the button "submit".

At last we are change the dynamic-form-question.component.html to take account the "group-questions"

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
  <label [attr.for]="question.key">{{question.label}}</label>

  <div [ngSwitch]="question.controlType">
    <input *ngSwitchCase="'textbox'" ...>
    <select *ngSwitchCase="'dropdown'" ...>
    </select>

    <div *ngSwitchCase="'group'" [formGroupName]="question.key">
       <app-dynamic-form [form]="form.get(question.key)"
           [questions]="question.questions"></app-dynamic-form>
    </div>
  </div> 

  <div  class="errorMessage" *ngIf="!isValid">{{question.label}} is required</div>

</div>
```

Yes, if we has a group-question, we show an app-dinamic-form pass as form "form.get(question.key)". It's the reason we changed the dinamic-form-component: to allow pass a formGroup and only create a new form if not pass the value.

In this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scq5ba?file=src%2Fapp%2Fquestion.service.ts) are the full example

NOTE: Personally I don't like the component create the formGroup. I like create the formGroup in the main.component and pass as argument

in [this other stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scq5ba-w6phr4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdynamic-form-question.component.html) explore this idea. The app-component has an ngOnInit that make the two calls

```
ngOnInit()
  {
    this.questions = this.service.getQuestions();
    this.form=this.qcs.toFormGroup(this.questions);
  }
```

And we need give value to the propertie "subGroup" of dinamic-form manually